# Use visual studio applicaiton that uses SQL LocalDB on a separate computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-2016-localdb

I have created a c# visual studio application that uses SQL LocalDB 2016 for its database. Visual studio only allows 2012 to be used as a prerequisite, but I was able to find a 2016 download online. I have tried both SQL LocalDB 2016 and 2017, but get the same error for both.

A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Ther server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. ... error 50...Cannot create an automatic instance.

I have ran sqllocaldb i on cmd and the result was MSSQLLocalDB which is the automatic instance for SQL LocalDB. The connection string in visual studio is set up for MSSQLLocalDB. I have uninstalled all other versions. The only thing I can think of that could be causing a problem is permissions. Thanks

Comment: Can you connect from SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Go to you Services panel and let us know what SQL Server services are listed and what is in parentheses after "SQL Server", since that is the instance name.

Comment: Program is running on computer A and database is running on computer B?

Comment: I should've clarified. I created the application on computer A, and it works perfectly fine. The application requires a database, which in this case is SQL LocalDB. Another words-Gusman: both program and program is on computer a and b. I am currently downloading SQL Server Management Studio. Influent-SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: On the computer that the application was written on I checked the services, and the only one that is related to SQL is SQL Server VSS Writer. What I don't understand the most is why the program is not working with the automatic instance yet it works on "computer A".

Comment: It could be a firewall, Browser service, etc.  There are several possible reasons.  If you google the error message you will find plenty of good resources.

Comment: I still never figured out why it was not able to connect to the automatic instance of MSSQLLocalDB, but I was able to make it work by creating a new instance on computer B, and change the connection string in the application to match the new instance name. If anyone else ever runs into this problem use command line, and type sqllocaldb create "CustomInstanceNameHere". Then change the connection string from MSSQLLocalDB or v13.1/14.0 etc. to be the instance name you just created. Re-publish it, and it should be good to go.